# Prevent Excel from updating absolute references when target is moved

Tags: microsoft-excel, openoffice-calc

I would like to prevent OpenOffice Calc or Microsoft Excel from updating absolute references when their target cells are moved.

For example, if cell B2 is "=$A$1" and you cut A1 and paste it in A2, B2 now says "=$A$2".

Is there any way to prevent this? It very easily leads to corruption of my carefully-crafted spreadsheets. (According to the OO.o issue tracker, [it's a feature](http://www.openoffice.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=103302)…)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try Excel's **INDIRECT()** function:

```
INDIRECT(ref_text,a1)
```

For example, if you always want to refer to cell A1, use the following syntax in cell B2:

```
=INDIRECT("A1")
```

In this fashion, B2 will always be equal to what A1 returns. For more info on this function, visit [this page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP052091391033.aspx).

Comment: It's a bit of a hack, and requires some work for large spreadsheets, but it seems to work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your answer inspired me to dig deeper in the function library. Turns out the OFFSET function will preserve AutoFill behavior but still prevent cut-paste corruption. So if I have values in A1:A10 I want to work with, I can use in B1 "OFFSET(B1;0;-1)" and autofill down.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know is to copy and then delete the original call (and intuitively and from personal expectation as a user I'd say that adjusting references to a moved cell is the right thing to do more often than not).